# How to deploy a Rails app to a VPS (or dedicated server)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vps

How can I deploy a Rails app to a VPS (virtual private server) or a dedicated server? It would be nice to have an easy to follow guide.

I know about scripts to automate the process, but I think it's better to have everything under control, in order to understand better the process.

Comment: I wrote an ebook about this topic (setting up a server from scratch and deploying an application manually using a nginx/Unicorn/MySQL/rbenv stack). It is intended to help you understand how everything in this process works under the hood and it's is free for people on my mailing list - you can get it [here](http://www.relativkreativ.at/ebook).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have successfully deployed a heavy Rails application to Linode or Digital Ocean, using these technologies:

- **rbenv** for Ruby installation
- **nginx + Passenger** for the application server
- **PostgreSQL** for the database server
- **Capistrano** to automate deploys (configure this first on your dev machine with your server IP and settings, I will not cover it here)

These are the steps that work for me:

## Setting up the virtual machine

**Create a new virtual machine**

Follow the setup instructions of your hosting, being Linode or Digital Ocean, to create the node and set it up.

**Set up date**

- dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

**Update packages**

- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade

## Security

**Create user**

- adduser deploy
- usermod -a -G sudo deploy
- logout

**Set up SSH key-authentication**

On local:

- ssh-keygen
- copy the public key:

  - scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub deploy@example.com:~

On the server:

- ssh deploy@example.com
- enable the alias to list files:

  - vim ~/.bashrc
  - uncomment all aliases
- mkdir .ssh
- mv id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys
- chown -R deploy:deploy .ssh
- chmod 700 .ssh
- chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
- logout (test the new authentication)

**Set up SSH**

- sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- Switch PermitRootLogin to no
- sudo service ssh restart

**Set up firewall**

- sudo iptables -L  (it should show a void table)
- sudo vim /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
- Paste this: https://gist.github.com/davidmles/89fc88e48e17cf8252bfca374e46355f#file-iptables-firewall-rules
- sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
- sudo iptables -L (now it should show the configured rules)
- sudo vim /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/firewall
- Paste this: https://gist.github.com/davidmles/89fc88e48e17cf8252bfca374e46355f#file-firewall
- sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/firewall

**Set up fail2ban**

Set up if you have enough free memory, as it tends to eat it.

- sudo apt-get install -y fail2ban

## Setup Ruby

**Install Git**

- sudo apt-get install -y git

**Install rbenv**

- git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
- echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
- echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
- source ~/.bashrc
- git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

**Install Ruby**

- sudo apt-get install -y curl gnupg build-essential
- rbenv install -l (look for the latest version)
- rbenv install 2.3.3 (or the latest available version at this moment)
- rbenv global 2.3.3
- rbenv rehash
- vim .gemrc

  - Paste this: gem: --no-document

## Setup servers

**Install nginx + Passenger**

- Install following the documentation:

  - https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/jessie/

**Install PostgreSQL**

- Install following the documentation:

  - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#PostgreSQL_packages_for_Debian_and_Ubuntu

## Setup libraries

**Install node.js**

Needed to pre-compile assets.

- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

**Install bundler**

- get install bundler
- rbenv rehash

## Setup the application

**Create the user in PostgreSQL**

- createuser username --pwprompt
- createdb -Ousername -Eutf8 db_name
- Test it:

  - psql db_name --user username --password

**Deploy the code**
   * On the server:
     * sudo mkdir -p /srv/yoursite.com
     * sudo chown deploy:deploy /srv/yoursite.com
   * On your dev machine:
     * bundle exec cap production deploy:check (it will throw an error because it doesn't find the database)
   * On the server:
     * cd /srv/yoursite.com/shared/config
     * vim database.yml (paste your database config)
     * vim secrets.yml (paste your secrets config)
   * On your dev machine:
     * bundle exec cap production deploy
     * bundle exec cap production whenever:update_crontab

**Configure logrotate**

- Follow this guide: * https://gorails.com/guides/rotating-rails-production-logs-with-logrotate

Comment: Great tutorial up to the part where I need to deploy, especially with pre-compiling assets and after it fails to find the rvm_shell

Comment: most of the gist link are dead.

Comment: @HaCos you are right, I have just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I deployed my rails application to my production servers (it's a cluster) with Capistrano before, but I found that Capistrano is a bit complex and sometimes even became trouble maker... So I wrote my deployment script by bash shell script.

I have put it on github with a brief guide: [deploy_rails](https://github.com/tangramor/deploy_rails)

Answer (score 0):

As more up to dated and future proof answer I would suggest this page on this:

[Deploy Ruby on Rails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/22.04)

Comment: That’s not the official page, but it’s an excellent resource though.