# Capistrano - deploying one app to same server twice, for staging and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

The documentation seems a little sparse on what this means.

I'm trying to set up an app deployed by a multistage capistrano script.

**EDIT:** I am trying to deploy the same app, twice to the same server. The only real difference (other than the git branches) is I want to deploy each copy to a different folder. The first instance is a staging where I can test the app in the exact same environment as the second instance, which is a production instance. Is capistrano able to do this?

I ran the staging deployment without any issues. However, when I run any tasks specifying my production stage, (such as deploy:setup, in this case) I receive the following error:

```
`deploy:setup' is only run for servers matching {:except=>{:no_release=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

Here's my Deploy.rb

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"

#server "direct.measuremyho.me", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :stages, %w{staging production} # Set staging and production environment
set :default_stage, "staging" # Use staging environment as the default one to prevent accidentally deploying to production 

set :application, "mmh"
set :user, "mmh"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
#set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 3

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@localhost:#{application}.git"
set :local_repository, "git@direct.measuremyho.me:#{application}.git"
#set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} nginx server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      sudo "#{try_sudo} service nginx #{command}"
    end
  end

  desc "restart passenger server"
  task :restart, roles: :app, except: { no_release: true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    # link the nginx config file in the app
    # sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf "\
    #      "/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
    # make the shared rails config directory
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    # ftp the database.yml file to that directory
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    # make the shared uploads directory
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
    # tell the user to edit database.yml
    puts "==> IMPORTANT!!! Now edit database.yml in "\
         "#{shared_path}/config <==="
  end

  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do

    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/uploads"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

end
```

My staging.rb

```
set :application_directory, "staging"
set :rails_env, "staging"
set :main_server, 'direct.measuremyho.me'
set :branch do
  default_tag = `git tag`.split("\n").last
  tag = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Tag to deploy (make sure to push the tag first): [#{default_tag}] "
  tag = default_tag if tag.empty?
  branch = "release/#{tag}"
  branch
end

# Do not modify
# Set up the server
server "#{main_server}", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/mmh/#{application_directory}"
```

My production.rb

```
set :application_directory, "production"
set :rails_env, "production"
set :main_server, 'direct.measuremyho.me'
set :branch, "master"

# Do not modify
# Set up the server
server "#{main_server}", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/mmh/#{application_directory}"
```

My question is, why is this being set? Additionally, what can I do to avoid setting this variable so I can use the deploy commands.

Let me know if I've missed any pertinent information.

Comment: Looks like the error is saying that the deploy:setup has already been run on that server.  Further, the server config seems identical in your staging and production environments.  So... maybe the staging deploy deployed to the same place as your production deploy is trying to deploy?

Comment: I'll edit my question, but essentially what I am trying to do is deploy two stages to the same server, in different folders, so that I can test new releases in the exact same environment as the production app. Can capistrano do this?

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. At least use two different users on the same machine.

Comment: I understand - I'm very new to this so I'm still trying to find my way around best practices. That being said, even if I use two different users, I am guessing I'd still run into this problem because I'm trying to deploy to the same server and the no_release flag is being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem for now by replacing the following line:

```
server "#{main_server}", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
```

with:

```
server "#{main_server}", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true, :no_release => false
```

in my production.rb file.

However, this is a hacky solution, and I'd like to understand how I should properly deploy a rails app twice to the same server, for staging and production purposes. Or alternatively, why I should not do this, and what the alternatives are. So, I have left the question unanswered.

I am attempting to expand on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444106/967668) helpful answer by providing a tutorial that includes its steps, as well as setting up a self-hosted git repository instead of github and deployment scripts for staging and production versions of the app on the same server. So this question answers a pivotal piece of this process. I'm trying to get an idea of what the best practices are for a situation like this.

Comments welcomed; I'll add them to this answer.

Comment: If this question is still interesting for future decisions: create two unix users, myapp_production and myapp_staging and deploy via capistrano multistage by defining a "task :production" and "task :staging" block in your deploy.rb which configures the path like 'set :current_path, "/home/#{user}/application/current"' and the user 'set :user, "myapp_production"'. All is then separated nicely.