# Problems deploying rails app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to deploy my rails 3.2.16 app to a VPS server. This is my time using capistrano so consider me a newbie. I'm running into a problem when I run "cap deploy:update" and I'm not sure what to do from here.

Below is the terminal output of what happens:

```
    ******-MBP:Folio stevo$ bundle exec cap deploy:update
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:21 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:21 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:**********/*********.git master-staging"
    command finished in 1626ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/********/app/*********/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/********/app/*********/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard c56df1b37c96846177a518133e89c1188b8d7a09 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master-staging git@bitbucket.org:**********/*********.git /home/********/app/*********/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/********/app/*********/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy c56df1b37c96846177a518133e89c1188b8d7a09; fi"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 3002ms
    copying the cached version to /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/********/app/*********/shared/cached-copy /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927 && (echo c56df1b37c96846177a518133e89c1188b8d7a09 > /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/REVISION)"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 1025ms
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:28 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:28 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public/assets && mkdir -p /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public && mkdir -p /home/********/app/*********/shared/assets && ln -s /home/********/app/*********/shared/assets /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public/assets"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 911ms
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:29 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927 && bundle install --gemfile /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/Gemfile --path /home/********/app/*********/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 1533ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927 && rm -rf -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public/ && ln -s -- /home/********/app/*********/shared/system /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/log && ln -s -- /home/********/app/*********/shared/log /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/log && rm -rf -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/********/app/*********/shared/pids /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/tmp/pids && rm -rf -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/config/application.yml && mkdir -p -- /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/config/ && ln -s -- /home/********/app/*********/shared/application.yml /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927/config/application.yml"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 940ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:32 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2013-12-26 20:29:32 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /home/********/app/*********/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /home/********/app/*********/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 903ms
  * executing "cat /home/********/app/*********/current/REVISION"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 920ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/********/app/*********/releases/20131227002927; true"
    servers: ["198.**.***.***"]
    [198.**.***.***] executing command
    command finished in 918ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cat /home/********/app/*********/current/REVISION'" on 198.**.***.***
```

Here is my deploy.rb file incase the problem is in here:

```
server '198.**.***.***', :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, '*********'
set :user, '*********'
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/app/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :rvm_type, :user

set :scm, 'git'
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:*****/#{application}.git"
set :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.strip

set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{ config/application.yml }

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

# Using Passenger
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end


# Skipping Asset Compilation With Capistrano
# http://www.bencurtis.com/2011/12/skipping-asset-compilation-with-capistrano/
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
end

require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that all for the error code? Why do you run `deploy:update` instead of `deploy`?

Comment: Hey Victor - I was following this guide (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13444106/303343), which recommend running :update first. However, running just deploy gives the same error message. Also, yes, that's the full error code. I first suspected that it was the assists precompiling that was giving me problems - which is how the last section made it into my deploy file.

Comment: I can't be of any help, I am sorry, but this is what I follow to get it working perfectly: http://railscasts.com/episodes/337-capistrano-recipes

Answer (score 0):

Your cap deploy is throwing an error in deploy:assets:precompile task which you have overridden in your deploy.rb please try to run cap deploy after commenting the below given code from your deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do

  namespace :assets do

  task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
    if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/  app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
    run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
    else
      logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
    end
  end
end
```

end